# Find the limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}$$

I only managed to show that:

$$8=\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}\leq\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}\leq\left(\frac{3^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}=27$$

I don't know how to bound it better, or maybe there is so simpler way?

Comment: hy don't you use L'Hospital?

Comment: the result should be $6\sqrt{6}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is exactly what i found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply L'Hospital's rule to limits of this kind; you just have to be a bit clever and introduce a logarithm:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x} &= \lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\ln\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}\\
&= \exp\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)^{3x}\\
&= \exp\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(3x\cdot\ln\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)\right)\\
&= \exp\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3\ln\left(\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}+3^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2}\right)}{x^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

That last limit is of the form $\frac00$, so it's ready for an application of L'Hospital's rule. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yup, I think I did this.

Comment: @TheMeff With first order Taylor expansion is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$2^{\frac {1}{x}}=e^{\frac {1}{x}\ln 2}$$

$$=1+\frac {\ln 2}{x}(1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$

by the same for $3$, the function becomes

$$e^{3x\ln (1+\frac {\ln 6}{2x}(1+\epsilon (x))}$$

using fact that $$\ln (1+X)\sim X \;\;(X\to 0) ,$$

we get the limit
$$ 6^{\frac {3}{2}} $$

Answer (score 0):

As it is who the power infinity form we subtract the (1/×)=t

=e^(lim t tends zero  [(2^t+3^t-2)/2])×(3/t)

Lim x tends zero( e^x -1)/x =ln(e )  .so (e) replace in above  question with 2 and 3 .
 so you get= e^[ 3/2 (ln2 +ln3 )]
     = e^[ln (6)^3/2]

=6^(3/2)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please read [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use it to typeset your Maths nicely so people can follow what you are saying easily

Answer (score 0):

Compute first the limit of the (natural) logarithm *and* do the substitution $x=1/t$:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\log\left(\left(\frac{2^t+3^t}{2}\right)^{1/t}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(2^t+3^t)-\log2}{t}
$$
This is the derivative at $0$ of $f(t)=\log(2^t+3^t)$; since
$$
f'(t)=\frac{2^t\log 2+3^t\log 3}{2^t+3^t}
$$
the limit is $\frac{\log 2+\log3}{2}=\log\sqrt{6}$.

Hence the original limit is $\exp(\log\sqrt{6})=\sqrt{6}$.